# What is the difference between isSameAs() and isEqualTo() in FEST?

Tags: fest

What is the difference between the two methods isSameAs() and isEqualTo() ?

The documentation says:

Verifies that the actual value is equal to the given one.

and

Verifies that the actual value is the same as the given one.

(http://fest.easytesting.org/assert/apidocs/index.html)

/Roger

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I could give you answer just from my general understanding.

isSameAs - checks if objects are same (e.g. checking if objects point to same **reference**)

isEqualTo - checks if objects are equal (e.g. checking if objects are equal based on **value**)

Hope it helps a bit